# simplexml XPath retrieving attribute, not text value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child id="childAtt">
            <subChild id="subAtt">Value to retrieve</subChild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

I am currently trying to retrieve the text value of subChild using this XPath:

```
$total = $xml->xpath("/*//child[@id='childAtt']/subChild[@id='subAtt']");
```

However, this returns the `subChild` attribute value and not the node's text value.

I want to know how to retrieve the text value of `subChild` with the id of `subAtt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access the first element and typecast it as a string:

```
$total = (string) $xml->xpath("/*//child[@id='childAtt']/subChild")[0];
var_dump($total);
```

Output:

```
string(17) "Value to retrieve"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to extract the text directly with your XPath query:

```
$total = (string) $xml->xpath("/*//child[@id='childAtt']/subChild/text()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query *does* select the element. Just to expand @Amal's answer, the result of your query is an array of all results that looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#2 (2) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(1) {
      'id' =>
      string(6) "subAtt"
    }
        string(17) "Value to retrieve"
  }
}
```

In words: the first element is a `SimpleXMLElement` instance whose string value is the desired text.

A complete example:

```
$string = <<<XML
<root>
    <parent>
        <child id="childAtt">
            <subChild id="subAtt">Value to retrieve</subChild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath("/*//child[@id='childAtt']/subChild[@id='subAtt']");

var_dump($result);
print (string) $result[0] . "\n";
```